# Android - List Connected Bluetooth Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an application that will listen for voice input through bluetooth if available and if not available then will read through the phone microphone.  I can't seem to find a way to check if their are any bluetooth devices already connected (not just paired).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got the solution for this. I am searching for same, Please provide answer.

Comment: No sorry, i never got a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (API >= 18):

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
List<BluetoothDevice> gattServerConnectedDevices = bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER);
for (BluetoothDevice device : gattServerConnectedDevices) {
    Log.d("Tag", "Found connected device: " + device.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: This is only for gatt devices. i need headphone, bluetooth headsets, etc.

Comment: I can get my ble mouse from this api, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, API 18 though.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getConnectedDevices(int)

Comment: Can you provide an example please.  Everything I have tried uses broadcast receivers, but I want to query in onCreate method.

Comment: FYI, this only works for BluetoothProfile.GATT and BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to list connected headset devices via [BluethoothHeadset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html) service

```
   btAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, object : BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {
            override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: Int) {
                //
            }

            override fun onServiceConnected(p0: Int, headset: BluetoothProfile?) {
                headset?.connectedDevices?.forEach {
                    Timber.d("${it.name} ${it.address}")
                }
            }
        }, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
```